# Usar um foreach com multiplicação entre números com 8 casas após a virgula + 100 horas

Tags: php

Estou tentando montar um foreach ou algo similar para que aconteça o seguinte:

Possuo um valor onde o mesmo é uma fração de `1`, no caso seria `0.00000100` ou seja, oito casas após o ponto. Além disso possuo uma data, por exemplo a data de ontem `23/04/2015 12:30:12`.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é multiplicar a fração `(ex: 0.00000150 * 3 = 0.00000450)` e na data adicionar `100` horas.

Um exemplo de como ficaria, sendo o valor base em `0.00000100 - dia 23/04/2015 14:38:45`, onde o mesmo será multiplicado por 3, algo do tipo:

```
$multiplicado = 3;
$string = '0.00000100 - dia 24/04/2015 12:24:45';
```

Onde o resultado seria uma lista mais ou menos assim:

```
0.00000200 - dia 28/04/2015 16:24:45
0.00000300 - dia 02/05/2015 20:24:48
0.00000400 - dia 07/05/2015 00:25:14
```

Seria uma lista mais ou menos como essa, onde pega o valor e multiplica a fração pelo mesmo e soma `100` horas. É pegar o que tenho hoje `0.00000100` e mostrar o que terei daqui `100` horas, `200` horas e `300` horas. Claro que coloquei multiplicado por `3`, mas pode ser mais ou pode ser menos.

Não sei se um foreach seria o ideal, mas acredito que sim... só não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia de como montar isso, ficaria grato. 
Obrigado

Comment: Multiplicar frações não é uma boa ideia Leandro. Números decimais são tratados como floats e não são representações exatas. Prefira usar um valor inteiro, e converta para segundos, por exemplo.

Comment: Certo, multiplicar uma determinada fração por 3, e somar 100 horas a uma data. Porém faltou você esclarecer o mais importante, essa operação deve ser executada até quando? X vezes? Até outra determinada data? Essa é a parte mais importante para determinar como sera o laço.

Answer (score 3):

Adapte sua ideia com as funções `date`e `strtotime`

```
<?php

    echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+100 hours', strtotime('24-04-2015 12:24:45')));
```

Comment: Olá Jhonatan, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda meu amigo, me perdoe a demora. É quase isso mesmo, pelo menos a linha esta certinha com o que procuro, contudo não estou conseguindo montar isso dentro de um foreach, como comentei... por exemplo, mudar apenas um 3 ou um quatro para que o mesmo apresente 3 ou 4 vezes. Mas obrigado mesmo pela sua ajuda